# ASP.NET Core 2.2 WebAPI: How to make PushStreamContent work

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to implement a simple push notification mechanism for a webpage. So I created a WebAPI controller with a method like this:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Subscribe()
{            
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response.Content = new PushStreamContent(
        (stream, headers, context) => OnStreamAvailable(stream, headers, context),
        "text/event-stream"
    );

    return response;
}
```

But when I try to call it from the client code:

```js
function listen() {
    if (!!window.EventSource) {
        const server = new EventSource('http://localhost:5000/api/Notifications/');

        server.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
            const json = JSON.parse(e.data);
            console.log('message', json);
        });

        server.addEventListener('open', function (e) {
            console.log('open');
        });

        server.addEventListener('error', function (e) {
            if (e.readyState === EventSource.CLOSED) {
                console.log('error');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Chrome replies me with an: `EventSource's response has a MIME type ("application/json") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection.`

I have to add that the code I'm writing is based on [this](https://www.strathweb.com/2012/05/native-html5-push-notifications-with-asp-net-web-api-and-knockout-js/) tutorial (which uses MVC5).

My question is: How can I make the `Subscribe` method work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this even possible in dotnet core yet?  https://techblog.dorogin.com/server-sent-event-aspnet-core-a42dc9b9ffa9

Comment: See this :https://forums.asp.net/t/1885055.aspx?ASP+NET+Web+API+and+HTML+5+Server+Sent+Events+aka+EventSource+ and this :https://techblog.dorogin.com/server-sent-event-aspnet-core-a42dc9b9ffa9

Comment: Well, it seems it's not possible to use `PushStreamContent` for that, even when I specify the `Content-Type` using the `IActionResult` approach, it tells me that I can't write messages because the body response is already closed. But I have found [here](https://www.tpeczek.com/2017/02/server-sent-events-sse-support-for.html) a quite interesting approach (totally discarding the use of `PushStreamContent`).